# Upgrade from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Online to CRM 2015 Online

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

One of our clients had purchased Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Online recently for implementation. As CRM 2015 Online is available now, is there any option for auto upgrade to CRM 2015, as no customization as been done so far. I couldn't find the information anywhere including http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-purchase-online.aspx. What are the upgrade cost/discounts involved if he's going for an upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Online organizations are upgraded at no-cost.

You will find the scheduled timeframe for the upgrade inside the Office365 portal.

Here the relevant Technet page:

[Manage Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online updates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn308237(v=crm.7).aspx)